# Does the Python 3.7+ spec guarantee `collections.OrderedDict is not dict`?

Tags: python

Does the Python spec guarantee that `collections.OrderedDict is not dict` will always evaluate to True? Have the devs ever expressed they will maintain `collections.OrderedDict` and `dict` as separate data types?

In other words is it expected that this code is "future proof" for new Python versions?

```py
# several ways to mostly say the same thing

assert collections.OrderedDict is not dict

assert issubclass(collections.OrderedDict, dict)
assert not issubclass(dict, collections.OrderedDict)

a = dict()
b = collections.OrderedDict()

assert not isinstance(a, collections.OrderedDict)
assert isinstance(b, dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would have to be true. The specification of `OrderedDict` says that comparisons between them are order-sensitive. But comparisons of ordinary `dict` objects are not order-sensitive. If the two classes were the same, this difference couldn't exist.